# When I open a new tab in Terminal the prompt goes to Home instead of the current path

Tags: pantheon-terminal

Previously in elementary OS when I opened a new tab, the new tab would open in the same location that I have in the existing tab. But now, it resets to home. How can I change this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is the expected behavior. If you want to open a new tab with the same location as the current tab, you can open a duplicate tab by right clicking on a tab and selecting "Duplicate".

If you'd like to permanently change the behavior so that new tabs always open with the directory of the currently focused tab, you'll need to use either dconf Editor or the `gsettings` command to set `org.pantheon.terminal.settings follow-last-tab` to `true`

Comment: Daniel I know that you're not a fan of editing elementary settings, but wouldn't some small settings like this, be available under some sort of terminal settings or configs?

Answer (score 1):

If you have [Elementary Tweaks](https://github.com/elementary-tweaks/elementary-tweaks) then you can go to ***Terminal*** and enable ***Follow last tab***.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the last version of ElementaryOS 5.1:

```
gsettings set io.elementary.terminal.settings follow-last-tab true
```